# Sentiment from Stanford CoreNLP via stanza: why only 3 classes?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm using the Stanford CoreNLP client for sentiment analysis, with the stanza package (because I mostly work in Python). I'd like to get sentiment scores using all 5 classes (from very negative to very positive) built into the CoreNLP system. I know that using the sentiment classifier built into stanza only uses 3 classes (positive, neutral, negative; https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/sentiment.html), but even when I access the CoreNLP server directly, I only get positive | negative | neutral. Why? Shouldn't the code below return sentiment scores across 5 classes, seeing as it uses CoreNLP itself?

```
import stanza
from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient

text=("This was the best movie ever made!")

with CoreNLPClient(
    annotators=['tokenize', 'ssplit', 'sentiment']) as client:
    ann=client.annotate(text)
    #print(ann)
    sentence=ann.sentence[0]
    print(sentence.sentiment)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stanza` by itself is a standalone module made with python.

The `CoreNLPClient` uses the actual CoreNLP. If you look at it's output carefully, you will see that it does give 5 level output, but it just rounds it up to 3 level in the end.

Try printing `sentence` instead of `sentence.sentiment` and you'll see.